# How to present data on macOS app like a calendar view in swift

Tags: swift, macos, calendar, nscalendar

I am creating a macOS application in Swift where I have core data that I store routes planned for a certain date and have a specific duration.
I need to present all routes on a page similar to a calendar where each route will be presented with a certain color (depending the driver).
How I can create this view?
Do I have to use any calendar object?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at cocoapods ?

Comment: Yes, I have sen this, but I need a daily calendar where I will have hours presented on the horizontal axis and then vertically to have the transfers (jobs) and how long each one takes.